# How to symmetrize a sparse matrix in Eigen C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, symmetric

I have a sparse matrix `A` in Eigen C++. Now I want to symmetrize it to another sparse matrix `Asym`:

I was hoping that it would be as simple as:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<FLOATDATA> A;
...
Eigen::SparseMatrix<FLOATDATA> Asym = 0.5*(A+A.transpose()); // error here
```

But due to obvious reasons, it gives the following assert failure error:

```
error: static assertion failed: THE_STORAGE_ORDER_OF_BOTH_SIDES_MUST_MATCH
```

My question is how to neatly do the above operation in Eigen C++?

Comment: Is A symmetric? If not, you may not add A and its transpose. In other words you may add two matrices, mxn and nxm if and only if m==n. I've also never seen a single formula where A + A^T is performed. Are you trying A^T x A, which makes a lot of sense at times.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to make your code compile is to evaluate the transposed matrix into a temporary of the correct storage order:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<FLOATDATA> Asym = 0.5*(A+Eigen::SparseMatrix<FLOATDATA>(A.transpose())));
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think doing this way will optimise away the temporary transpose?

Comment: It does not get rid of the temporary -- and I don't think there is an efficient algorithm to add sparse matrices with different storage order (maybe unless you can exploit some special structure of the matrix).